# Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 keeps dropping connection

Tags: networking, 16.04

I bought a new DELL Inspiron 15 and installed Ubuntu 16 and having trouble staying connected to the internet.

I'm using my iPhone's hotspot via USB to access internet. But the connection keeps dropping every 1-5 minutes. I have to unplug the USB cable and reconnect to get internet access again. Using this method seems to randomly freeze the whole system as well.

Using Bluetooth to connect to my phone results in a stable connection and the computer does not freeze anymore. But this method is quite slow.

I also went to a coffee shop for wifi, which seems to work so far.

What i tried so far is editing the wired connection for the phone in network settings an set IPv6 to ignore.

I also ran `sudo apt-get update` & `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` with no success.

`lspci | grep -i net` shows me this as my network adapter:

`01:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)`